# Можно ли на PHP вызывать функции и получать значения таким образом

Tags: php, классы

Вот так:

```
$class->group->func();
$class->group->value;
```

И если можно, то как?

Comment: Можно. каждая функция возвращает `$this`  то есть себя или  другой объект

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите на это последовательно, слева направо. Что возвращает `$class->group` ? Если это объект (может, сам же `$class`, а может и другой), у которого есть метод `func()` или свойство `value` – то такие конструкции обычное дело.

```
$class->group->func();
// то же самое, что
($class->group)->func();
```

Это называется method chaining - выстраивание методов в цепочку, цепочка вызовов.

Пример ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3724136/556876)):

```
<?php
class chainClass {
    private $result;

    function __construct() {
        $this->result = "";
    }

    function plusA() {
        $this->result .= "aaa";
        return $this;   // <- вот он, секретный соус!
    }

    function plusB() {
        $this->result .= "bbb";
        return $this;   // <- вот он, секретный соус!
    }

    function getResult() {
        return $this->result;
    }
}

$a = new chainClass();
$a->plusA()->plusB()->getResult(); // "aaabbb"
```

Поскольку методы `plusX()` возвращают сам объект, можно дальше в цепочку приписывать новые вызовы методов этого объекта. Можно и длиннее:

```
$a->plusA()->plusB()->plusB()->plusB()->plusA()->getResult();
// "aaabbbbbbbbbaaa"
```